# Error recording wav due to apparent incompatible settings, issue arose after upgrading to 10.9

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm recording audio using an AVCaptureSession, and everything worked fine until 10.9.
I set these settings:

```
[newAudioSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM]     forKey:AVFormatIDKey];    
[newAudioSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]  forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[newAudioSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[newAudioSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

and call (the session is started before calling this, of course)

```
[audioFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:<File URL> outputFileType:AVFileTypeWAVE recordingDelegate:<delegate>];
```

This used to work great, but now the recording stops immediately, and the error from didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL is:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11805 "Cannot Record" UserInfo=0x6180000ee580 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The combination of audio file type and audio format in audioSettings is not supported, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again., AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false}
```

Looking at the error code (-11805), it states that no data could be written. It appears that there is some incompatibility between the wav format and those settings, but I fail to see how that is the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you are sure this code still works under 10.8?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have it currently running on another machine that is 10.8